# Как отобразить список интерфейсов по SNMP в TheDude?

Tags: snmp

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!
Рисую в TheDude специфичные железки, инфы по которым мало, да и SNMP на них, видимо, какой-то нестандартный. Нестандартность выражается в том, что snmpwalk в программе отображает кучу информации, а в настройках устройства на карте на вкладке SNMP пусто. Соответственно и нет интерфейсов в выпадающем списке на линках между ними.

[image: не отображает инфу по SNMP, а snmpwalk показывает кучу всего]

От производителя получили MIB'ы в виде кучи файликов .txt, .mib и .wri. Dude эти wri не ест, скормил, переименовав их в txt, но ситуации это не исправило.
Задача - отображать на линках текущую загрузку канала и рисовать график, как это легко умеет "дудя" с любой циской или другим, попадавшемся мне коммутатором/маршрутизатором. Сам нахожу oid'ы с перечнем интерфейсов и битрейтом на них.

[image: Я так понимаю, это список интерфейсов]

То, что надо:

[image: А это битрейт, правда ещё не понял как из него получить мегабиты...]

В какую сторону копать, чтобы дудя в своём классическом виде понимала интерфейсы и видела трафик на них?